# Difference between Free and FreeImage for TRasterImage variables?

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

In my Lazarus project, I use variables of 
`TPortableNetworkGraphic` type, which is inherited from `TRasterImage`. Until now, I have released them with the `Free` method, but I have noticed that for these types also a `FreeImage` method exists.

What is the difference between these two? Which one should I use, or should they be called both?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: It says: "FreeImage - method for freeing or detaching image from the Raster." (https://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.io/docs/lcl/graphics/trasterimage.freeimage.html). This does not answer my second question, if calling FreeImage is necessary before calling Free.

Comment: It would be very rare to have to do anything more than call Free. FreeImage is just a way to reclaim some internal resources without destroying the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we investigate the methods we find the following:

Method `Free` originates from `TObject`. Calling it destroys your class instance.

Method `FreeImage` comes from `TRasterImage` and is equal to `SetHandle(0)` method from the same class. The latter technically deals mainly with `FSharedImage`variable (`TSharedRasterImage` class instance) and its `Handle` property. In other words after calling `FreeImage` the instance of `TPortableNetworkGraphic` class instance will be still "alive".

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But because I don't see under the hood so much, I am still unsure, if calling just Free (not preceded by FreeImage) is okay, or if it can leave an unbound bitmap in memory...?

Comment: Calling Free is enough.